# Simulate SIP phone in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I've installed GoAutoDial Call Center Software. Due to our ancient phone equipment - until we upgrade it - I'm trying to use it only as a call management software for outbound campaigns. So I can present the phone number to agent , etc. without actually dialing it. agent will still do that by hand.

The problem is that agent disconnects in approx. 20 seconds (no sip phone present). I've tracked down this to asterisk.

From the asterisk log :

```
NOTICE[15426] channel.c : Unable to request channel SIP/8001
```

Is there a way to simulate a dummy sip phone , so it doesn't throw the client out ?
Or are there any obscure settings to prevent this (otherwise desirable) behavior ?
I was looking at /etc/conf/asterisk/sip.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local channel to do call via dialplan. After that you can call client, if fail wait, call again etc. As needed

```
exten => s,1,dial(Local/exten@context/n,,)
```

You have setup nat correctly so your agents always online and setup at agents phone re-registration inteval to 20 sec or less.

Comment: So this will stop asterisk disconnecting the agent application even if phone isn't present ? I have no way to connect those landline phones to anything but 25 years old Kapsch pbx - asking this because you're talking about setting up the phone re-registration at the end.

Comment: That depend of dialplan. You cna orginize dial the way it not even know/check real phone.